# Listing all entries in one section related to entries written by currentUser in another section

Tags: entries, relations

The setup:

**Section A** *(entries I want to list)*

**Section B**

- entries field (related to 1 entry from SectionA)

**My goal is to list all entries from Section A, that are related to an entry in Section B  authored by the currentUser.**

Right now what I'm doing is looping through all entries in Section B authored by the current user and querying/displaying the entry related to it, but it's way too inefficient and eats up a lot of database queries. Was hoping there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Not sure whether or not there's a way to achieve this sort of relation via a complex relatedTo or if I need to go another route.

Can provide additional information/clarification if anything is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
{% set sectionBEntries = craft.entries.section('B').authorId(currentUser.id) %}

{# 'relatedTo' works both ways, so we can use sectionBEntries 
    as input for relatedTo to get all section A entries that have 
    a relation to one of the section B entries by currentUser #}
{% set sectionAEntries = craft.entries.section('A').relatedTo(sectionBEntries) %}

{% for entry in sectionAEntries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Had no idea that you could use groups of entries in relatedTo like that, 'doh. Many thanks!